# I get Invalid login when I try to login

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, identity, .net-5

I use ASP.NET Core 5.0 MVC.

If I register a user with email `admin@telia.com` from `https://localhost:44315/Identity/Account/Register`, this works fine. I now add a role Admin in the table `AspNetRoles` manually. I now add the id for `admin@telia.com` from table `AspNetUsers` into table `AspNetUserRoles` and add the id from table `AspNetRoles` to table `AspNetUserRoles`.

When I know login using `admin@telia.com` I can see in the menu that those menu item that was protected from unautorize user is now visible. I now remove `admin@telia.com` from table `AspNetUsers` and remove role admin from table `AspNetRoles`.

Now I have done seeding that will automatically add a new user with `admin@telia.com` with password Pissen30060! if it doesn't exist and also add a new role admin and connect the new user `admin@telia.com` to role admin. If I look in the database I can see that `AspNetUsers`,  `AspNetRoles` and `AspNetUserRoles` is correct.

I have an id value in AspNetUsers for user admin@telia.com and I have an id value in table AspNetRoles for the admin role. In table AspNetUserRoles I have one row where the UserId and RoleId match those from AspNetUsers and AspNetRoles. So all should work but when I try to login using admin@telia.com with password Pissen30060! I get Invalid login attempt. I have compared the row from table AspNetUsers when I can log in and when I can't login and it all columns seems correct. I hope someone could explain when I should do.

//Tony Johansson

Comment: Hi @user2658578, any updates about this case?

Answer (score 0):

> I have done seeding that will automatically add a new user with admin@telia.com with password Pissen30060! if it doesn't exist and also add a new role admin and connect the new user admin@telia.com to role admin.

> when I try to login using admin@telia.com with password Pissen30060! I get Invalid login attempt.

Please try to check if you assign same value to `UserName` and `Email` properties in your seeding data code logic.

Besides, please check if the `RequireConfirmedAccount` option is set to `true`  while configuring Identity service as below, which would cause this issue if the registered user login with that account but not confirming the account.

> options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true